# connected trees in ui-tree drag n drop prevention

Tags: angularjs, tree, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-tree, angular-dragdrop

I am using I'm using : 
http://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/connected-trees
I want to be able to drag on parent level but not on child level in the tree.

How would I go about that. I am using their code for now which I can put here

html

```
<!-- Nested node template -->
<script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer1.html">
  <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content">
    <div class="tree-node-content">
      <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)"><span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed}"></span></a>
      {{node.title}}
      <a class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="remove(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
      <a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="newSubItem(this)" style="margin-right: 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="node.nodes" ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
    <li ng-repeat="node in node.nodes" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer1.html'">
    </li>
  </ol>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="nodes_renderer2.html">
  <div class="tree-node">
    <div class="pull-left tree-handle" >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="tree-node-content">
      <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)">
        <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{
          'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed,
          'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed
          }">
        </span>
      </a>

      {{node.title}}

      <a class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="remove(this)"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a>
      <a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="newSubItem(this)" style="margin-right: 8px;"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="node.nodes" ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
    <li ng-repeat="node in node.nodes" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer2.html'">
    </li>
  </ol>
</script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <h3>Connected Trees</h3>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h3>Tree 1</h3>
    <div ui-tree id="tree1-root">
      <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="tree1">
        <li ng-repeat="node in tree1" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer1.html'"></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h3>Tree 2</h3>
    <div ui-tree id="tree2-root">
      <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="tree2">
        <li ng-repeat="node in tree2" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer2.html'"></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<h3>Data binding</h3>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <pre class="code">{{ tree1 | json }}</pre>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <pre class="code">{{ tree2 | json }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

and the controller is

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('demoApp')
    .controller('ConnectedTreesCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.remove = function (scope) {
        scope.remove();
      };

      $scope.toggle = function (scope) {
        scope.toggle();
      };

      $scope.newSubItem = function (scope) {
        var nodeData = scope.$modelValue;
        nodeData.nodes.push({
          id: nodeData.id * 10 + nodeData.nodes.length,
          title: nodeData.title + '.' + (nodeData.nodes.length + 1),
          nodes: []
        });
      };

      $scope.tree1 = [{
        'id': 1,
        'title': 'tree1 - item1',
        'nodes': []
      }, {
        'id': 2,
        'title': 'tree1 - item2',
        'nodes': []
      }, {
        'id': 3,
        'title': 'tree1 - item3',
        'nodes': []
      }, {
        'id': 4,
        'title': 'tree1 - item4',
        'nodes': []
      }];
      $scope.tree2 = [{
        'id': 1,
        'title': 'tree2 - item1',
        'nodes': []
      }, {
        'id': 2,
        'title': 'tree2 - item2',
        'nodes': []
      }, {
        'id': 3,
        'title': 'tree2 - item3',
        'nodes': []
      }, {
        'id': 4,
        'title': 'tree2 - item4',
        'nodes': []
      }];
    }]);

}());
```

Thanks

**What I have tried **

This is what I tried

```
    $scope.tree2Options = {
        beforeDrop : function (e) {
            //console.log("sent from tree 2");
            var destValue = e.dest.nodesScope.node ? e.dest.nodesScope.node.value : "pata nehi";
            //console.log(destValue);
        },
        accept: function(sourceNodeScope, destNodesScope, destIndex) {

            //console.log("tree 2 before accepting ");
            console.log(destNodesScope.$element.attr('data-type'));
            return true
        }
    };
```

and then

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h3>Tree 2</h3>
    <div  data-ui-tree="tree2Options" id="tree2-root">
      <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="tree2" data-type="{{tree2.id}}">
        <li ng-repeat="node in tree2" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer2.html'"></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
```

but console.log does not give me any ids or anything. I was thinking to add an attribute and then check for it

** A hacky fix **

so i did this which kinda fix it but its very hacky...I would still need to know why I cant get ids and why this works...basically if I drop in node since node[] so it has id undefined and it gives undefined and I check for that..which gets the job done but I hate it as its so hacky

```
    accept: function(sourceNodeScope, destNodesScope, destIndex) {

        //console.log("tree 2 before accepting ");
        console.log(destNodesScope.$element.attr('data-type'));
        if(destNodesScope.$element.attr('data-type') != 'undefined'){
            //return true
            console.log("true");
            return true;
        }else{
            console.log("flase");
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

ok after certain trial and errors figured it out

this is what I did..i create the data-type as suggested above in the html

```
 <div class="col-sm-6">
    <h3>Tree 2</h3>
    <div  data-ui-tree="tree2Options" id="tree2-root">
      <ol ui-tree-nodes="tree2Nodes" ng-model="tree2"  >
        <li ng-repeat="node in tree2" ui-tree-node ng-include="'nodes_renderer2.html'" data-type="{{node.allowed}}"></li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then I added the following

```
accept: function(sourceNodeScope, destNodesScope, destIndex) {

                var allowed = false;

                angular.forEach(destNodesScope.$element[0].children, function (item) {
                    var attr_allowed = item.attributes['data-type'] && item.attributes['data-type'].value ? item.attributes['data-type'].value : false;
                    if(attr_allowed && attr_allowed=="allowed" ){
                        allowed = true;
                    }
                });

                return allowed;

            },
```

works now

thanks